# pop up window automation with selenium ide 4.0.0

Tags: popup, selenium-ide

I am automating testing with selenium ide 4.0.0. I need to click 'ok' button from the pop up window. I am not able to automate this. Everytime i need to manually click ok. Any idea how to achieve this.

I have tried giving accept(); in the script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.